# Azure SQL DB: create users with PowerShell, parametrized SQL scripts and Azure Key Vault

Tags: sql, powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-keyvault

Goals:

- Create users in an existing Azure SQL database
- The username shall be passed as parameter to the SQL script that creates the user
- The password is stored as secret in Azure Key Vault and shall be passed as parameter to the SQL script that creates the user
- Assign certain permissions to the users created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Store the passwords of the user as well as the admin in Azure Key Vault

  - [Add a secret to Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/quick-create-portal#add-a-secret-to-key-vault)
- Create the SQL script to create the user and assign permission using dynamic SQL

  - A good overview of existing permissions: [Azure SQL DB Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017#chart-of-sql-server-permissions)

Code:

```
DECLARE @username VARCHAR(50) = '$(username)';
DECLARE @password VARCHAR(50) = '$(password)';
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(50) = 'xxx';

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE NAME = ' + CHAR(39) + @username + CHAR(39) + ')
    BEGIN
        CREATE USER ' + @username + ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + CHAR(39) + @password + CHAR(39) + ';
        ALTER USER ' + @username + ' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = ' + @schema + ';
    END

--ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER @username;
--ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER @username;
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::' + @schema + ' TO ' + @username + ';
GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA::' + @schema + ' TO ' + @username + ';
GRANT UPDATE ON SCHEMA::' + @schema + ' TO ' + @username + ';
GRANT DELETE ON SCHEMA::' + @schema + ' TO ' + @username + ';
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::' + @schema + ' TO ' + @username + ';
';

EXECUTE (@query);
```

- For PowerShell:

  - It is necessary to use a user and its credentials in the connection string that has the permission to create users
  - The 'hack' from secure to plain password is necessary to be able the passwords in the connections string respectively in the SQL script
  - It assumes that the SQL script is on the same level or some subfolder of the PowerShell script
  - It is necessary to have the SQL module installed

    - `Install-module -Name SqlServer -Scope CurrentUser`

Code:

```
$passwordAdminSecure = (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $adminSecretName).SecretValue
$passwordAdminPlain = (New-Object PSCredential "user",$passwordAdminSecure).GetNetworkCredential().Password

$dbConnectionString = "Server=tcp:$serverName.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=$dbName;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=$username;Password=$passwordAdminPlain;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"

$script = Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -Include scriptname.sql -Recurse

$userToCreate = 'xxx'
$passwordUserSecure = (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $userSecretName).SecretValue
$passwordUserPlain = (New-Object PSCredential "user",$passwordUserSecure).GetNetworkCredential().Password

Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $script -ConnectionString $dbConnectionString -Variable username=$userToCreate, password=$passwordUserPlain -Verbose

Write-Host "Added user $userToCreate!"
```

- Via the following query you can check existing users with the assigned permissions

Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    pr.principal_id, 
    pr.name, 
    pr.type_desc, 
    pr.authentication_type_desc, 
    pe.state_desc, 
    pe.permission_name
FROM sys.database_principals AS pr
JOIN sys.database_permissions AS pe
    ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr.principal_id;
```

Comment: When somebody gets this running with `execute sp_executesql` please add your solution. I repeatedly ran into troubles with the correct notation for the parameters. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> I repeatedly ran into troubles with the correct notation for the parameters.

You're mixing SQLCMD variables and TSQL variables.  It's tricky.

When writing SQL from PowerShell, I find it's much better to let Powershell's build the final query.  Like this:

```
$username = "joe"
$password = "23948230948"
$schema = "dbo"


$sql = @"
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE NAME = '$username')
    BEGIN
        CREATE USER $username WITH PASSWORD = '$password';
        ALTER USER $username WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = $schema;
    END


GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::$schema TO $username;
GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA::$schema TO $username;
GRANT UPDATE ON SCHEMA::$schema TO $username;
GRANT DELETE ON SCHEMA::$schema TO $username;
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::$schema TO $username;
"@

invoke-sqlcmd $sql
```